# Reverce many to one hierarchy

Tags: php, mysql, design-patterns

I have an app that collects and processes user infromation.

```
CREATE TABLE registrations(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(50),
    email VARCHAR(50),
    email_id INT
);

CREATE TABLE email(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    email VARCHAR(50),
    person_id INT

);

CREATE TABLE person(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50)

);
ALTER TABLE registrations 
   ADD FOREIGN KEY (email_id) REFERENCES email (id);

ALTER TABLE email 
   ADD FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES person (id);
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3247)

The workflow is:
-process the registration info,
-if the email is new add it, else assign it.
-if the person is new add it, else assign it.

**Example** code:

```
function newRegistration($input){
   $registraton = new Registration();
   $registraton->setUsername($input['username']);
   $registraton->save();

   $email = null;  
   if(Email::exists($input['email'])){
       $email = Email::find($input['email']);
   }else{
       $email = Email::create($input['email']);
   }

   $registraton->setEmailId($email->getId());
   $registraton->save();//!!

   $person = null
   if(Person::exists($input['name'])){
       $person = Person::find($input['name']);
   }else{
       $person = Person::create($input['name']);
   }

   if(!$email->getPersonId()){
       $email->setPersonId($person->getId());
       $email->save();//!!
   }
```

}

The code is just example,  in the real implementation there are more triggers and dependancies, and the Order of processing the events:
**Registration->Email->Person**

This is clearly not conveniant way to update the just created elements ... I m looking for e disign-patern or DB architecture how to optimize this scenario.

**EDIT**:
There may be multiply registration with one Email,
there may be multiple emails to one Person.

Comment: `sidenote:` you miss labeled `person_id` as `parson_id`

Comment: Could you provide the relationships between those tables? To me it seems you'd better merge everything in a single table, unless there are some one-to-many relationships. Since you are using PHP, you don't really need to "update the just created elements", just create them once when you got all the mandatory information to populate the database.

Comment: I would suggest that rather than checking a record exists you just insert a new one using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax. Using this you can trigger it to return the id of the new record or the id of the existing record if one is found.

Comment: After your edit `There may be multiply registration with one Email, there may be multiple emails to one Person.` this sounds "different than usual", would you provide an example with some data as well? How do you enforce the relationship between email address and person? I don't think you want an email address to be used by more than one person, do you? Specify the `FOREIGN KEYS` in your schema, this will help us to better understand the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I have hard time understanding why registration attempt with a name that exists in a system but different email should result in associating different email with existing user. Typically in a systems like that emails are treated as unique IDs which they are and new users are forced to choose non-existent username. Also if this is a typical interactive registration there is most likely no need to store registration attempt in a separate table. If you really want users to be associated with more than one mail the better approach might be to treat initial registration email as primary and allow loggedin users to add secondary emails to their account.

Comment: Good point. The registration is not used for login, it just data that is processed from this app (it comes from different sources)

Comment: it's difficult to help with the system design without knowing a bit more about the purpose and preferred outcome of that user regs processing. One thing that seems obvious to me and might simpift things is email_id in registrations table. I think it's redundant and potentially violates the rule of sigle point of truth in a system. Other thing is I'd consider registrations as input and the data saved in person and email as processed results. This way all subsequent processing and current state of the system is represented by only those two tables. hth